# Where can I find this CV template

Tags: moderncv

I want the code source for this CV, I have searched in `moderncv` template but 
I didn't find the .tex for [this one](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/7/cv_7_banking.pdf):

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: How about: http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/7/cv_7.zip

Comment: @DG' no there are not this style

Comment: Surely it is, have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/). Chances are that `moderncv` is already included in your distribution.

Comment: I'm using a native TexLive (2018) and the template is located in `texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/examples/template.tex` of my TexLive installation.

Answer (score 13):

To reproduce the example do:

- Download http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/7/cv_7.zip
- Unzip
- Open cv_7.tex
- Change line 28 to `\moderncvstyle{banking}`

Which will look like this in the end:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{banking} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

\clearpage

\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```